# Length of line segments using only +-*/

Tags: geometry

If we have eg. 10 line segments (whatever direction and length) and we know the start and end coordinates of each and the euclidean length of only one of them. Is it possible to calculate euclidean lengths of all other segments using only operations +-*/?

The idea is to calculate lengths using only computationally light functions (+-*/) and avoid using computationally intensive functions (cos,sin,tan,sqrt). I know that line segment length can be calculated using sqrt(adjacent*adjacent+oppocite*oppocite), but I don't want to use it for performance reasons.

Comment: Can you get away without computing the square roots?

Comment: I would say, it is not possible.

Comment: Division isn't that fast and square root isn't that slow. There is a [MO Post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7724061/how-slow-how-many-cycles-is-calculating-a-square-root) which talks about speed of taking square root.  On Core2 65nm, FADD/FMUL/FDIV/FSQRT takes 3 / 5 / 9-38 / 9-69 clocks cycles to complete. On Core2 45nm, division and square root got faster, FADD/FMUL/FDIV/FSQRT now takes 3 / 5 / 6-21 / 6-20 clock cycles. If you are concerned about the speed of square root, you also need to worry about the speed of your division.

Comment: @achille: That's true, but sqrt needs also one addition and two multiplys to get the length. By the way, I know, that length of all segments that are parallel or perpendicular to the known line segment, are easy to calculate using ratios of taxicab lengths of segments. Also length of square diagonal is easy to calculate. But I cannot find a way, if known segment and unknown segment are not parallel or perpendicular or unknown one is not a square diagonal.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to calculate euclidean lengths of all other segments using only operations +-*/?

It is not. Assuming your coordinates are rationals, perhaps even integers. Then the lengths will in general still be irrational numbers, and no finite combination of your elementary operations can compute an irrational number from a set of rational numbers.